# Limit inheritance of intermediate abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class, `CreatureBehaviour`, that provides a `TakeTurn` method. The goal of this is to decide what the creature should do, and it should provide its response via callback. This is because the response may require player input, so it shouldn't block other processes.

```
public abstract class CreatureBehaviour {

    public abstract void TakeTurn (Action<TurnAction> response);

}
```

Inheriting from this, the `PlayerControl` class stores the `response` callback for later decision-making. Most of its content isn't relevant, but ultimately it must invoke `response` when the player does something.

```
public class PlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour {

    Action<TurnAction> responseCallback;

    public override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response) {
        responseCallback = response;
    }

    // Various UI callbacks that can send something to "responseCallback" when appropriate.

}
```

And all non-player creatures need to be able to send a callback too. For safety, I want to ensure that a callback is always hit, so I've created an abstract `NonPlayerControl` class that ensures a response:

```
public abstract class NonPlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour {

    protected abstract TurnAction TurnResponse ();

    public override void TakeTurn (Action<TurnAction> response) {
        response (TurnResponse ());
    }

}
```

With this, all of my non-player creature behaviours can derive from `NonPlayerControl` and simply implement `TurnReponse()`. The compiler guarantees that all their scripts will return a response, rather than leaving the callback hanging. Note that `PlayerControl` can't implement `TurnResponse()` because it would need to guarantee an immediate return, and that would block other processes.

So I want to derive other classes from `NonPlayerControl` and maybe from `PlayerControl`, but I don't want to accidentally derive another class from `CreatureBehaviour` and risk missing the callback.

Is there any way I can "sort of seal" `CreatureBehaviour` so that it can only have these two direct children and prevent any others? If not, is there a better pattern I could be using here?

Comment: you may want to explore monads / functional programming: https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad  seems like you want to be able to do method chaining

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you could do for this in a "normal" way, but there's one option you *could* consider...

If you give your `CreatureBehavior` class just a *private* constructor, then nest `PlayerBehavior` and `NonPlayerBehavior` within that class, they will have access to the private constructor but no other classes will... so no other classes could derive from `CreatureBehavior`.

A simpler solution would be to:

- Document in `CreatureBehavior` that it shouldn't be subclassed directly
- Write unit tests to validate that there *aren't* any other subclasses

That can only test your code rather than code in other assemblies, of course. If you don't *need* these from other assemblies, then make the classes internal instead of public. Even if you need all the classes to be public, you could include a no-op abstract internal method that's implemented in `PlayerBehavior` and `NonPlayerBehavior` - that will stop classes outside your assembly from deriving from `CreatureBehavior` as they can't implement the internal abstract method.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick idea, without further testing: Could you use a generic to do the restriction?

```
public abstract class CreatureBehaviour<T> where T : IPlayerControl, INonPlayerControl {
    // ...
}
```

And then use it in the following way:

```
public abstract class NonPlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour<NonPlayerControl>, INonPlayerControl {
    // ...
}

public abstract class PlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour<PlayerControl>, IPlayerControl {
    // ...
}
```

It is sort of a hack, but it might work for your case.

Comment: That's how I'd implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prohibit inheritance from the CreatureBehavoiur class but you can limit access to TakeTurn methods by combining internal, sealed and protected access and place it in the separate assembly:

```
public  abstract class CreatureBehaviour
{
    protected abstract void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response);
}

public class PlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour
{
    private Action<TurnAction> responseCallback;

    protected override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        responseCallback = response;
    }

    internal void TurnByPlayer(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        TakeTurn(response);
    }

    // Various UI callbacks that can send something to "responseCallback" when appropriate.
}

public abstract class NonPlayerControl : CreatureBehaviour
{
    protected abstract TurnAction TurnResponse();

    protected override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        response(TurnResponse());
    }

    internal void TurnByNonPlayer(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        TakeTurn(response);
    }
}

public sealed class CreatureStearing
{
    public void Turn(PlayerControl control)
    {
        control.TurnByPlayer((action) => {});
    }

    public void Turn(NonPlayerControl control)
    {
        control.TurnByNonPlayer(action => {});
    }
}
```

Now you can inherit from PlayerControl, NonPlayerControl, and even CreatureBehaviour in other assemblies, but you cannot use TakeTurn methods for any class intances other than PlayerControl and NonPlayerControl that are in separate assemblies:

```
public class SomeTest1 : PlayerControl
{
    protected override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        base.TakeTurn(response);
    }
}

public class SomeTest2 : NonPlayerControl
{
    protected override TurnAction TurnResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        base.TakeTurn(response);
    }
}

public class SomeTest3 : CreatureBehaviour
{
    protected override void TakeTurn(Action<TurnAction> response)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

....

var t1 = new SomeTest1();
        var t2 = new SomeTest2();
        var t3 = new SomeTest3();
        var creatureStearing = new CreatureStearing();
        creatureStearing.Turn(t1);
        creatureStearing.Turn(t2);
        creatureStearing.Turn(t3); // 'Cannot resolve method 'compile error here
```

Of course you can pass this limitation by declaring internal access for your assembly, but it requires to implement something like CreatureStearing (well some efforts) but other party in this case will know for sure this is a hack.